# Flash-style Tween/Easing Functions in C#

Tags: c#, tween

[Flash-style Tween/Easing Functions in C#](http://theinstructionlimit.com/flash-style-tweeneasing-functions-in-c)

I came across this post on the internet today. Has anyone had experience in using tween/easing before as I would love to know where it would be used in programming using C#? Could it be used in WinForms? What application template would you use this with?

Comment: What post? I don't see any link.

Comment: That [post](http://theinstructionlimit.com/flash-style-tweeneasing-functions-in-c)? Can't you just paste a link?

Comment: I am not talking only about 1 single post. I am discussing about all posts to do with tween/easing in C#. having a link to 1 post would be pointless

Comment: Hmm. Your question is not that clear then, because you said `I came across *this* post`, so I thought you were doing a reference to a specific post.

Comment: @Otiel, I apologise in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own animations by using StoryBoards and Blend is really nice to do this with a timeline in WPF but if you are asking if there are libraries for like GreenSock : I don't know...